# How to read in a text file starting at a certain line in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read in a text file with the delimiter "|" from line 19 onward. How would I go about this? Here is what I have tried:

`data <- read.table("text.txt", sep = "|")`

This just returns one very long column and the delimiter didn't seem to sepearate it correctly. Also, how do I let R know I want to start reading in data at line 19?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `skip` argument of `read.table` to skip lines 1-18.

Comment: `skip = 18` is what you are looking for just as @Greg mentioned